# How to get a Doctrine2 Entity method from a Symfony2 Form in Twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm in a Twig template, and I have a "form" variable that represents a Doctrine2 Entity Form.

This Entity has properties that are mapped into the form, but the Entity has also some methods that I would like to access from my Twig template.

I would love to do something like this:

```
{{ form.myMethod }}
```

or maybe something like this:

```
{{ form.getEntity.myMethod }}
```

but unfortunately it doesn't work.

How could I achieve what I need?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To access your entity from your FormView in a twig template you can use the following code

```
{{ form.get('value') }}
```

Where form is your FormView object. This will return your entity and from there you can call any methods on it. If you embed a collection of entities or a single entity in your form you can access it the same way

```
{{ form.someembedform.get('value') }}
```

or

```
{% for obj in form.mycollection %}
  {{ obj.get('value').someMethod }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: What if "mycollection" is an entity field ?

Comment: Note that I've just got a problem with Symfony 2.3: `{{ form.cp.get('id') }}` didn't work but `{{ form.cp.vars.id }}` works. So Philipp Rieber's anwser seems more accurate.

Comment: In Sf2.3 this also does not seem to work anymore. Can't access the entity in Twig, only can access the entity id

Comment: Symfony 2.6 keeps working with `{{ form.cp.vars.id }}`

Answer (score 18):

An even more convenient syntax to get the underlying entity instead of:

```
{{ form.get('value') }}
```

is this:

```
{{ form.vars.value }}
```

Then you can call any entity method like this:

```
{{ form.vars.value.someMethod }}
```

See also [the Form chapter in the Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#form-variables-reference).

Answer (score 15):

Just in order to update the subject:

```
form.get('value')
```

is deprecated since symfony 2.1. Copy from Symfony\Component\Form\FormView :

```
/*
 * @deprecated Deprecated since version 2.1, to be removed in 2.3. Access
 *             the public property {@link vars} instead.
 */
public function get($name, $default = null) ....
```

so, I guess

```
form.vars.value.youMethod()
```

should be the way to go. It has worked form me.

... and there it goes my first post here. hope it helps!

Answer (score 6):

Lost few hours trying to figure out what's going on and why

```
{{ form.vars.value }}
```

is NULL.

If you have form.element (not the form object itself) object, for example if you are overriding a form_row template that has passed the form.row object, you can get the Entity like this:

```
{{ form.getParent().vars.value.MyEntityMethod }}
```

hope that helps someone!

EDIT: Year and so later - another useful tip:

```
{% block sonata_type_collection_widget %}
    {% for child in form %}
        {{ child.vars.form.vars.value.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: It helped, thanks ! Note that with SF2.3, getParent() does not exist, replace by "parent" e.g. form.parent.vars.value.getId()

Answer (score 3):

object methods should work in twig, I know I used them in some project.

try to use `()`

like `{{ form.myMethod() }}`

Comment: The form is managed by FOSUserBundle. I tried your suggestion and this is the error I have: Method "myMethod" for object "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" does not exist in "FOSUserBundle:Profile:edit_content.html.twig" at line 20

Comment: Well that error means that twig does try to call form.myMethod() method, but doesn't find it. In other words, now you just need to implement it correctly.

Comment: I ended up overriding the FOSUserBundle controller and passing the entity to the template. That way I can use methods.

Comment: How can I pass arguments to `myMethod()`? i'm trying doing `myMethod(100,50)`, but it doesn't seem to work, and I dont know how to debug it... any idea? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that at some point the *value* is actually **null**. So you can use

```
{{ (form.vars.value != null) ? form.vars.value.yourEntityMethod():'' }}
```

tested in SF v3.0.6.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me in **version 2.6.7**. I used [customised form widgets](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#method-2-inside-a-separate-template) to achieve this:

```
{# src/AppBundle/Resources/views/Form/fields.html.twig #}
{% extends 'form_div_layout.html.twig' %}

{%- block entity_widget -%}
    <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
    {%- for n, child in form %}
        {{- form_widget(child, {
            'entity': form.vars.choices[n].data
        }) -}}
        {{- form_label(child) -}}
    {% endfor -%}
    </div>
{%- endblock %-}

{%- block radio_widget -%}
{# You now have access to entity #}
{%- endblock %-}
```

Answer (score -1):

use `{{ form.getData.myMethod }}`.

Comment: Method "getData" for object "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" does not exist in "FOSUserBundle:Profile:edit_content.html.twig" at line 20