# Symfony2 Accessing each entity field elements value in Twig

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I have one form that contains entity type field `parameters`:

```
            ->add('parameters', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'SPlaceBundle:Parameter',
                'query_builder' => function(ParameterRepository $er)
                {
                    return $er
                            ->createQueryBuilder('s')
                            ->where('s.type = :type1 or s.type = :type2')
                            ->setParameter('type1', 1)
                            ->setParameter('type2', 2)
                            ->orderBy('s.name', 'ASC');
                },
                'property' => 'name',
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
            ))
```

As you can see I only display parameters with type=1 or type=2.
While rendering template I would like to place hr (or something else) between checkboxes representing different parameter types.
I was trying to use {{ field.get('value').type }} trick to get parameter type:

```
{% for p in form.parameters %}
    {{ form_widget(p) }} 
    {{ form_label(p) }}
    {{ p.get('value').type }}
    <br>
{% endfor %}
```

The problem is that above `{{ p.get('value') }}` returns `parameter id (int)` instead of `parameter object`.
Is there a way to return object?

Comment: Maybe these answers will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134216/how-to-get-a-doctrine2-entity-method-from-a-symfony2-form-in-twig , 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755728/how-to-access-an-underlying-object-from-a-twigs-formview-in-a-template

Answer (score 0):

It's not really elegant, but you could concatenate the type and name in your select, and use that as label. Then, when displaying the labels, split on the delimiter and you have both type and name.

Comment: It's not a solution. I've mentiond about the type but what if I wanted to display also other properties (e.g. longtext)?

Comment: The [entity field type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html) extends the choice type. So you could use the choice_list property to manually define your choices. If the choices are put in an array, it's displayed as an optgroup with options by default. But you can change this in your template.

Comment: When I try to use choice filed type with `choice_list` property i get this error: "Expected argument of type "array", "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection" given" at ArrayToBooleanChoicesTransformer ->transform (object(PersistentCollection)) 
in vendor\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Form.php at line 991