# Access mapped entity from form in Twig

Tags: twig, symfony-forms, symfony-2.4

I have a entity mapped to a form, but I don't want to have all fields editable, but still want to show the value.

For example this is my form type:

```
class GameHasPlayerType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('inTeam', new TeamPositioningCheckboxType())
            ->add('positionX', new TeamPositioningNumberType(), array(
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'in-table'
                )
            ))
            ->add('positionY', new TeamPositioningNumberType(), array(
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'in-table'
                )
            ))
            ->add('exchanged', new TeamPositioningCheckboxType())
        ;
    }
}
```

This type has a custom form template:

```
{% block team_positioning_widget %}
    {% spaceless %}
        <td>
            {{ form_widget(form.inTeam) }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ form.player.firstName }} {# Player is not in the form, but inside the mapped entity #}
        </td>
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

From the form I want to reference to the mapped entity and access fields that are not added to the form.

How can I access the mapped entity from the form object?

Comment: This is a duplicate to [How to get a Doctrine2 Entity method from a Symfony2 Form in Twig](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134216/how-to-get-a-doctrine2-entity-method-from-a-symfony2-form-in-twig/30344827#30344827). I posted an answer relevant to **version 2.6.7** there.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can access the mapped entity through the form.vars.data attribute.

```
{{ form.vars.data.firstName }} {# The data attribute is the Player instance #}
```

Or as the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#form-variables-reference) says through form.vars.value:

> You can access the current data of your form via form.vars.value:
>
> `{{ form.vars.value.firstName }}`

Comment: This does not work. `{{ form.vars.value }}` is null as well as `{{ form.vars.data }}`

Comment: How do you create your form in your controller? Do you pass your entity as data: `$this->createForm(new GameHasPlayerType(), $entity);`

Comment: No I create this form in a parent form like this: `$builder->add('subForm', new GameHasPlayerType())`

Comment: Aaah, now I got it. I needed to set the `data` key to the entity in the options array. Thank alot for your help :)